# Can we delete a highly up voted but off-topic and closed question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, on-hold

About half a day ago, it seems there was an issue with some Facebook servers and a question like [Suddenly stopped Facebook login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47567376/suddenly-stopped-facebook-login) popped up. It was closed as off-topic within a few hours but it has gained 22 up votes (and 4 down votes) at the time of this writing and a highly up voted and accepted answer.

Clearly this was a temporary support issue and not really a valid programming question. It has no value to any current or future readers. Can this question (and a few linked duplicates) be deleted?

Comment: Oh wonderful.  A totally off-topic, not-programing-related, social media support annoyance.  16 upvotes and a 23-upvote answer.   I don't know - how do we get rid of high profile, ephemeral trash?  Can the mods do it, or does SO staff have to get nvolved?

Comment: "Can we delete a off-topic and closed question?" Yes.

Comment: There's a bigger underlying problem here... at least 23 people who have earned the voting privilege and were online yesterday are using it incorrectly, upvoting off topic questions.

Comment: @DavyM all those people who worked tirelessly to gain....uuuuh...[15 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)? If only that were enough for users to start using the site right!

Comment: @AndrawDeak Very good observation. Since I'm pretty sure that the `15 rep = upvoting privileges` is a Stack Exchange universal thing milestone, I don't think anything will ever happen to change that. Maybe an alert when a question is deleted could be made available to everyone who upvoted the deleted post that the question was off topic and should not have been upvoted? I dunno... I'll look to see if there's a question addressing the issue of people upvoting off topic quesitons.

Comment: @DavyM: that's democracy for you.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Ah, the joys of service outage questions. Every time one of Apple's, Google's, or Facebook's servers hiccup we get piles of these.

Usually we delete them once the problem has been resolved, so I've deleted this one and its duplicates.

Comment: Maybe a migration to a better suited site had been non-destructive solution.

Comment: @peterh It was a brief and temporary support issue. Such a question has no place anywhere on the SE network.

Comment: @peterh: Agree with rmaddy and Brad that this has no place anywhere on SE.  However, if it had been a more interesting question, it might have been appropriate for [webapps.se].

Comment: @rmaddy 1) There is no such close reason, and particularly not delete reason. 2) There are a lot of "brief and temporary support issues" on the SE sites everywhere, these are not always very upvoted questions but they are tolerated. 3) The logic is: if a similar problem would happen again, people could easier find the question with google keywords.

Comment: @Kevin Right. Thus, my opinion is: this question should have been migrated to the webapps and not deleted. Note also its high score.

Comment: That high score means nothing. There are entire classes of users who don't know how to use their votes correctly.

Comment: @peterh: There is an explicit policy not to migrate low quality questions, which this clearly was (source: I'm looking at it right now).  The only general answer to these questions is "Wait a while and then try again."  It's not viable to have a separate question for every outage.

Comment: @BoltClock It is a strong argument, although I have no way to check the real value of this question now. However, typically high voting score means the popularity of the given content and posts with high score should be preserved. But I don't think it had been the data loss the century.

Comment: @Kevin The question had a high voting score, see my previous comment.

Comment: @peterh: I just looked at it now.  The high score was clearly undeserved.  It only got upvoted because other people were having the same problem.

Comment: @peterh: Yes, "typically". There are fringe cases. This is one of them. Since you admit that this isn't the data loss of the century, why are you so hung up on keeping the question around? (Had it been more of a general "What can I do when X goes down?" question than a ["Is X down for everyone or just me?"](http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com), it would probably have more value, but alas.)

Comment: @peterh Putting a question like this anywhere on SE would be pointless. The question was asked on SO because people suddenly had issues with their apps. Very few devs would ever see this question on another SE site. In fact, there were two other exact duplicate questions posted on SO. So not only would people not see this question if it were to be migrated, people didn't even see it (or bother to search) on SO before posting duplicates. There's simply no benefit to keeping such off-topic questions around.

Comment: If there was anything redeeming in the answers, such as a workaround for people facing this issue in the future, I won't delete the question. However, if the answers consist of "the servers were down, and now they're up", there's nothing that can help someone seeing this going forward. These questions get ridiculous numbers of "me too" votes because people seem to think that voting on things here will bring them to the attention of Google, etc. This clutters up the top questions in tags, so removing questions of no future value keeps things clean.